# Creating a SKLabelNode with system font (UIFont to font name)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, uikit

I am trying to create an Apple Watch SpriteKit app that has a lot of SKLabelNodes inside of it and I am trying to match the default watchOS as closely as possible while using bold, regular, and light weight in my fonts.

The problem is that while I can get a UIFont for what I need I can not however translate that into a SKLabelNode's font.

Here are some attempts. None of them work because the fonts are not found or it does not compile due to types not matching:

```
SKLabelNode(fontNamed: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 99, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold))
SKLabelNode(fontNamed: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 99, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold).familyName)
SKLabelNode(fontNamed: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 99, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold).description)
SKLabelNode(fontNamed: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 99, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold).fontDescriptor)
```

How can I use system fonts inside of a SpriteKit app? If this is impossible what is a good font that is close enough to the system font for my use?

Comment: Why didn't you try `.fontName`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want bold font you can do it this way:

> SKLabelNode(fontNamed: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16).fontName)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore as of iOS 13. You must rather rely on the `attributedText` property to set custom fonts and weights to your `SKLabelNode`'s text.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the .fontName property and call the font name with the desired weight.

Example:

```
let exampleOfText = SKLabelNode (text: "here is your text")
  exampleOfText.fontSize = 50.0
  exampleOfText.fontName = "SFPro-Black" //font weight
```

note: use the Font Book to help you! :)